# OpenCv, check if a mouse click is near a Point2f?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a `std::vector` of `cv::Point2f` values.
I have a `Point2f` which is the current mouse position.

```
cv::Point2f mousePnt;
std::vector<cv::Point2f> maskPnts;
```

I have a function that checks if the current mouse click point is contained in the vector, and if so, removes it:

```
if (std::find(maskPnts.begin(), maskPnts.end(), mousePnt) != maskPnts.end())
        {
            std::cout << "found pnt: " << mousePnt << std::endl;
            maskPnts.erase(std::remove(maskPnts.begin(), maskPnts.end(), mousePnt), maskPnts.end());
        }
```

What I would like to do is add a margin of error to this. So that if the mouse click is within, say, 20 pixels of an existing value, that existing value is still removed from the vector.

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not do a simple (circle based) calculation directly?

Comment: create a circle at the mouse click and search inside, you mean?

Comment: Hmm, the tolerance should be applied to the vector right? May be I was thinking to hastily here. But anyways, checking for the matching vector points within the circle around the mouse click point, should work as well.

Comment: for each point: if(sqrt((mouseX - pointX)^2 + (mouseY-pointY)^2) <= 20) thisPointIs20OrLessPixelsAwayFromMouse;

Comment: take a look at [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/9317) you can try the [code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sturkmen72/opencv/8bb3863f529e381bc67e477a84c2f451e5cd1c2d/samples/cpp/warpPerspective_demo.cpp)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. Based on the comment above, I have this function working:

```
for (int p = 0; p < maskPnts.size(); p++)
        {
            if (std::pow(sqrt(mousePnt.x - maskPnts[p].x),2) + std::pow((mousePnt.y - maskPnts[p].y),2) <= 20)
            {   
                maskPnts.erase(maskPnts.begin() + p);
            }
        }
```